# How to know if a radiobutton is checked?

Tags: php

I'm working with an examination page using php connected to a MySQL database. I'm currently on the part where i need to check if the the answers checked on the radiobutton is correct.

QUESTION: How will i know which radiobutton is checked, and how will i know if the answer on that radiobutton is equal to the data in the database? I want to display the "CORRECT" if it's the same or "INCORRECT" if it's wrong in a different page.

Here is my PHP code for the radiobuttons:

```
$sql = 'SELECT q_question, q_correct, q_answer2, q_answer3, q_answer4 FROM tblquestions WHERE     q_category = "' . $legend3 . '" ORDER BY rand() LIMIT ' . $limit3;

$retval = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
if(!$retval)
{
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{   
$span1 = $row['q_question'];
$obj1 = $row['q_correct'];
$obj2 = $row['q_answer2'];
$obj3 = $row['q_answer3'];
$obj4 = $row['q_answer4'];

$my_array = array($obj1, $obj2, $obj3, $obj4);

shuffle($my_array);
$rad1 = $my_array[0];
$rad2 = $my_array[1];
$rad3 = $my_array[2];
$rad4 = $my_array[3];

echo '<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">';
echo '<tbody><tr><td colspan="2" width="300" height="40"><span id="question1">' . $count . '. ' .         $span1 . '</span></td></tr>';
echo '<tr><tbody><tr><td width="50%"><input name="q' . $nameCTR1 . '" type="radio" class="validate[required] checkbox" id="a[I1A]" value="'. $rad1 .'">A. ' . $rad1 . '</td>';
echo '<td width="50%"><input name="q' . $nameCTR1 . '" type="radio" class="validate[required] checkbox" id="a[I1B]" value="' . $rad2 . '">B. ' . $rad2 . '</td></tr></tbody></tr></tbody>';
echo '<tr><tbody><tr><td width="50%"><input name="q' . $nameCTR1 . '" type="radio" class="validate[required] checkbox" id="a[I1C]" value="' . $rad3 . '">C. ' . $rad3 . '</td>';
echo '<td width="50%"><input name="q' . $nameCTR1 . '" type="radio" class="validate[required] checkbox" id="a[I1D]" value="' . $rad4 . '">D. ' . $rad4 . '</td></tr></tbody></tr></tbody></table>';
echo '<hr width="100%"></hr>';

$nameCTR1 = $nameCTR1 + 1;
```

Comment: Do you know how to handle submitted html forms in php?

Comment: If you're talking about method and action in html forms, yes i know how to handle it. i just need to know if the checked radiobutton is the same as the data in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkbox and radio type filed does not get posted when they are unchecked or not-selected.

So in your action script(the one which you have set in action attribute of form) you can check whether their value has been set in $_POST (if your form method is POST) or not.

If it exist then it implies that fields are checked or selected else not.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. i was able to do it because of this. I had to jumble the codes to get the right combination and I eventually got it. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a function for you.  Just call the function getRadio(name of radiobutton here) and it will return the value if it was checked.

```
function getRadio( $radioName ) {
    $radio = $_POST[ $radioName ]; // RADIO NAME IS DEFINED IN HTML

    if( isset( $radio ) ) {
        return $radio;
    }
    return $radioName . " is not set";
}
```

*Also this assumes you are using the post method

Comment: `function getRadio( $radioName ) = {` - what's this `=` for?

Comment: `(String) $radio = $_POST[ $radioName ]` This will emit notice if `$radioName` key is not set.

Comment: I was able to do what I want to do. I didn't use this code but i had an idea on how to do it because of your answer.  I wish I can vote up this. Thank you so much :)

Comment: if you would please select this as the answer so I can get points I would appreciate it a ton :)  Glad it helped you out.